# querying negative numbers(Integer,float) in cloudant

Tags: javascript, cloudant, nosql

I have some lattitudes in my nosql document and Im not having problems when I try : myurl?lat=10 (for example), the problem occurs trying to querying negative numbers like this: myurl?lat=-10 which it throws me the following error:

> Cannot parse '((($fieldnames:_5fid_3a*) OR ($fieldnames:_5fid.*)) AND
>   (lat_3anumber:-10))

I have this in my code for parsing string to numbers and querying them:

```
if (req.query.lat != undefined) selector.selector.lat = Number(req.query.lat);
```

where: req=request and lat = lattitude

Im using cloudant, any elegant solution?? (I need float for lattitudes and integer numbers for other fields, both negative and positive). Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: That code is weird. What's the point of using the ternary operator like that?

Comment: because i want to filter by some fields and adding them to my selector variable after _id :     var selector = {
        "selector": {
            "_id": {
                "$exists": true,
            }
        }
    };

for querying with one or more fields if they arent setted in my url query, do you know a better way??

Comment: I meant it is weird to have it return `req.query.lat == undefined` at a point when you know that that will evaluate to `true`, so why not simplify it to `(req.query.lat == undefined) ? true : selector.selector.lat = Number(req.query.lat);`? And given that you aren't assigning the result of the whole ternary to anything else it could be simplified to `if (req.query.lat != undefined) selector.selector.lat = Number(req.query.lat);`.

Comment: thank you!!its too early in the morning XDDDDD .... but i continue having problems with negative numbers in my query if i have myurl?lat=-10 for example

Comment: If `req.query.lat` contains the string `"-10"` then it should work. What does `console.log(req.query.lat)` show?

Comment: it shows me the good number : -10 but the problems is with this for querying, cloudant says me the error posted in my question if I try this:

    var selector = {
        "selector": {
            "_id": {
                "$exists": true,
            },
            "lat": -10
        }
    };

Comment: Wait, so you're saying the line of code shown in the question works to convert the argument to a number `-10`, but then when you later use the `selector` variable it gives the error? Maybe [edit] your question a bit to explain that more clearly.

Comment: edited!! the problem in the parsing is in cloudant not in javascript with Number or parseInt or parseFloat, the things is when im searching for a negative number in my nosql document, cloudant cannot parse them.